# "Хвостики" аббревиатур

Tags: аббревиатуры

Речь о таких словах, как например, МЧС-овец. Но ведь это "-овец", а еще лучше в родительном падеже — "-овца", звучит по меньшей мере смешно.
А как правильно писать такие слова? Может, не ставить дефис?

Answer (score 1):

Зачем издеваться над словами? Можно сказать просто "спасатель".

> мой дружок, беспартийный, потешался надо мною: "КП-эсэсовец!"

В то время могли такой юмор позволить?

Answer (score 0):

Помнится,я был членом партии, так мой дружок, беспартийный, потешался надо мною: "КП-эсэсовец!" А в этом случае как поступить? Как вы считаете? "Капээсэсовец"?

Comment: Есть слово коммунист, оно лучше. "Запишите меня в КП! - ??? - В СС я уже был..."